# Emacs start with a given mode

Tags: emacs

Can we open up a file in emacs with a given mode (e.g. for90-mode) from the command line? I want to start this way from a script (bash) function.

Comment: `emacs` usually accept the `-e` option that causes it to evaluate its arguments as elisp expressions. You could use this to evaluate an expression that switches to a specific mode and then opens a file (or the other way around).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-eval` option to run whatever commands you want.

For example, this opens emacs in the terminal, opens a new named buffer, and switches to ruby-mode:

```
emacs -nw -eval '(progn (switch-to-buffer "new_script") (ruby-mode))"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your filename is named correctly (usually the extension) then `auto-mode-alist` should handle this for you.

If needed you may need to add to `auto-mode-alist` in order to make `for90-mode` be the one that is started for you.

Answer (score 0):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879531/188574) works for me (tried to open emacs in magit mode).

```bsh
emacs -nw -f <mode>
```

That means

```bsh
emacs -nw -f magit
```

for me.

I am using Emacs 27.2 on Linux.